# não tô conseguindo importar meus repositorios do git para o github, alguém me ajuda?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

quando tendo levar um repositorio para o git dá o seguinte erro:

```
PS C:\git> git remote add origin https://github.com/edielsoncosta/modulo.git

    >> git branch -M main

    >> git push -u origin main

    error: remote origin already exists.

    Everything up-to-date

    branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.

    PS C:\git>
```

alguma idéia do que posso fazer?

Answer (score -2):

O comando `git remote add ...` serve exclusivamente para adicionar uma origem remota ao seu git local, ele deve ser executado apenas quando você quer adicionar uma nova origem remota.

Você pode conferir um pouco mais aqui: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote/pt_BR

---

Mas agora vamos ao seu problema, veja que o erro que você está recebendo é o:
`error: remote origin already exists.`
*tradução livre: uma origem remota com o nome de "origin" já existe*

Isso significa que você já executou o comando `git remote add origin <url-do-repositorio>` em algum momento, para você conferir qual é a url que você adicionou ao **origin** você pode rodar o comando: `git remote get-url origin`.

Se essa não for a url, então, você pode atualizar ela com o comando `git remote set-url origin <nova-url>`

E para finalizar, o comando `git push` foi rodado, e o resultado foi **Everything up-to-date**, ou seja, tudo está atualizado remotamente conforme o seu repositório local.